# Visual Studio 2010 'Go to Definition'/f12 not working correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a rather large VS win32 solution that has multiply projects in it. The main project is an .exe with several other .exe's and .dlls that interact with each other. Up to about a month ago I was able to hit F12 or right click on a function and select 'Go to Definition' or 'Go to Declaration' and poof I was looking at the correct piece of code.
Recently when I hit F12 it produces a list of places, in the 'Find Symbol Results' window, where the function is declared/defined. Which is really annoying!

If I use F12 on a function that is being imported from a dll it takes me to that declaration/definition no problem. F12 only seems to have a problem with bringing up the code in the current project, which is set as "Set as startup Project". This is a c++ solution and a lot of these functions are overloaded, but still as I said a month or two back I had no problem of F12ing to the correct function/code.

Any suggestions as to what might have happened.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried exiting visual studio and deleting the .ncb file and letting it recreate it?  That file can sometimes become corrupt and/or rather large.

Comment: @rrirower I'm pretty sure 2010+ does not have .ncb files, but has .sdf files instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using VS 2012.  But, the concept is the same.

Comment: Tried to edit my post but don't think it took, anyway; Closed all windows open in VS, 'cleaned' solution, deleted .sdf file and rebuilt solution. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Check **Tools->Option->keyboard->find Command(Edit.FindAllReferences)**
your shortcut key f12 might be assigned to that

to resolve in **keyboard ->find command(Edit.GoToDefinition) -> assign f12 in global**
Remove all other Works assigned this shortcuts key
(Shortcut currently used by dropdown)

[F12 finds all references, not go to definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799187/f12-finds-all-references-not-go-to-definition)